# Magento 2 State and City Tax

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-calculation

Currently working adding US State and City Tax for US Store.

Each state in America has different Tax amounts that must be added to sales, but within those States there can also be City tac which must also be added on top of.

For example, Washington has a State tax of 6.5% (for example), the city of Bellevue in Washington has a City tax of 3.5% (for example), meaning that anyone ordering to Bellevue Washington would need to pay 10% tax on sales.

I was wondering if there is a way to combine these two together somehow?

I have added the State Tax in Magento Admin using the Tax Zone and added to the Tax Rules, this works correctly for the state.

Now for the city tax, I have repeated to process in adding the Tax Zone, but have added the Postcode range. But it only takes a range of postcodes which doesn't work properly.

Example, if Bellevue has the following postcodes: 1,2,3,4,6
And i put a postcode range from 1 and to 6

Once in the checkout and add the correct shipping details BUT put a postcode of 5, it picks up the Bellevue city tax which is not what i want to happen, it should revert back to the state tax.

Hope this is understandable.